# How to speed up reading files of a project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, liferay-6

I have a liferay 6.2 project with thousand files in source folder
I use eclipse IDE to develop and it has a annoyed issue: each time I click a folder in eclipse, it take long time to open the folder to see files and subfolders
I have config the eclipse.ini of eclipse to tuning eclipse performance but it does not have any effect.
Please me the suggestion to speedup eclipse

Bellow is the content of eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2048M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
4096m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m
-Xverify:none
```

Comment: That looks like Eclipse Kepler which is now 19 releases old, how about trying something newer with an up to date Java. Current versions of Eclipse can still develop code for older versions of Java.

Comment: I’m currently using Luna eclipse
It takes more 10s when I click a folder/package to expand in the project in eclipse

Comment: Luna is still 7 years and 18 releases old. This may also depend on your operating system / file system - some file systems don't perform well with large folders.

Comment: At last I use Liferay-developer-studio to develop, it is fast and have many functions supporting for liferay